# SAS - Can I create a table of all table names within a library and then all variables within those tables?

Tags: sas

I would like to create a new table with all tables contained within a library and the variables within each of those tables. I know I can use something like the below to get the table name but I cant find much on getting each variable. I have multiple libraries and each has potentially hundreds of tables. Any help really appreciated.

```
proc sql ;
  create table mytables as
  select *
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname IN ('WORK','SPDSWORK',etc)
  order by memname ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use distionary.columns instead.

```
proc sql ;
  create table mytables as
  select *
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname IN ('SASHELP')
  order by memname ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use PROC CONTENTS with the special _ALL_ member name.  Use the NOPRINT option to suppress the output and the OUT= option to name the dataset with the contents information.

```
proc contents data=mylib._all_ noprint out=contents;
run;
```

Comment: This is what i was doing but i was then having to search for key words in a results page/word doc that wasnt user friendly. Hence the need for a table so i can query that table for key words or export to share with others. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Huh?  Your response makes no sense.  The posted code produces no output, it only produces the dataset CONTENTS which will have variables like MEMNAME, NAME, TYPE etc.  Added more words to describe the code better.

Comment: Thanks your edit - makes more sense to me now and is perfect for checking one library. My apologies for not understanding first time round. You may have already guessed my SAS experience totals under 1 month...